# qwt plot curve axis not visible

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I am using qwt plot curve to draw curve.
the x axis and the y axis are not visible, only the curve is visible.
How to show the axis with showing some first, last and middle values in 
the scale interval of the axis

Comment: go through http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html it may help you

Answer (score 2):

I give you a small example:

```
   // xBottom - x-axis yBottom - y-axis

    plot->setAxisMaxMinor(QwtPlot::xBottom, 2);
    plot->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, 0, MAX_X_VALUE, 2);
    plot->setAxisMaxMinor(QwtPlot::yLeft, 2);
    plot->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, 0, 1, 1);
    plot->setAxisMaxMinor(QwtPlot::yLeft, 1);
    plot->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, -1, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should have some QwtPlot object. I assume you want to draw xBottom and yLeft axes.

```
QwtPlot *plot=new QwtPlot(this);
//following 4 lines may not be required because
//QwtPlot defaults are to show xBottom and yLeft axes
//and you use autoscaling for these axes
plot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::xBottom);
plot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::yLeft);
plot->setAxisAutoScale(QwtPlot::xBottom,true);
plot->setAxisAutoScale(QwtPlot::yLeft,true);
```

You already have it if you were using QtDesigner and QwtPlot widget with it. You can access it with ui->plot

2) You should have

```
QwtPlotCurve * curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
//.... attach some data to curve
curve->attach(plot);
```

3) Probably you want to call replot

```
plot->replot();
```

Comment: And don't forget to populate QwtPlotCurve with the data by using setData or setSamples